# How do I keep the mask when slicing a masked array in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

When I create a view of a Numpy masked array (via slicing) the mask is *copied* to the view -- so that updates to the view will not change the mask in the original (but will change the data in the original array).

What I want is to change **both** the original data **and** the original mask when updating the view.

From the [Numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#indexing-and-slicing):

> When accessing a slice, the output is a masked array whose data attribute
>   is a view of the original data, and whose mask is either nomask (if there
>   was no invalid entries in the original array) or a copy of the
>   corresponding slice of the original mask. The copy is required to avoid
>   propagation of any modification of the mask to the original.

#### Example

```
import numpy.ma as ma

orig_arr = ma.array([[11,12],[21,22]])
orig_arr[1,:] = ma.masked

print orig_arr
## Prints: [[11 12]
##          [-- --]]

view_arr = orig_arr[1,:]
print view_arr
## Prints: [-- --]

view_arr[:] = [31,32]
print view_arr
## Prints: [31 32]

print orig_arr
## Prints: [[11 12]
##          [-- --]]
print orig_arr.data[1,:]
## Prints: [31 32]
```

As you can see the data in the original array has been updated, but
the mask hasn't.

How do I make updates in the view affect the mask in the original array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try turning off the mask in the view before changing the value

```
orig_arr = ma.array([[11,12],[21,22]])
orig_arr[1,:] = ma.masked

print orig_arr
## Prints: [[11 12]
##          [-- --]]

view_arr = orig_arr[1,:]
print view_arr
## Prints: [-- --]

view_arr.mask=False # or [True, False] 


view_arr[:] = [31,32] 
print view_arr
## Prints: [31 32] #or [-- 32]

print orig_arr
## Prints: [[11 12]
##          [31 32]] # or [-- 32]
```

Comment: I was a little doubtful about this working, but it does.  But my tests also showed some unpredicatible changes/non-changes.  I'd have to look more at the `ma` code to properly understand why this works.

Comment: I agree, it seems somewhat inconsistent.

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that the actual mask is in `arr._mask`, while `arr.mask` is property, with a `.__setmask__` method.  So there is 'magic' going on when you do `arr.mask=[...]`.

Comment: Apparently `view_arr._mask` is initially a `view`, and `view_arr.mask=...` changes it with `[...]` (preserving the link).  But `var_arr[:]=[]` creates a new `_mask`, breaking the link.  So the view mask is a 'lazy' copy, not an actual one, until you modify the `view`.  I tested this by looking at `x._mask.__array_interface__`.

Comment: This seems to work contrary to the way the documentation describes it: isn't this likely to break in later versions of Numpy?
Very weird behaviour – thank you for the workaround though! :)

Comment: My guess is that the documentation needs refinement.  But I'd suggest searching the github issues for any relevant discussions.